# spring boot configuration properties for a class in external jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jar, external, properties-file

i have a jar file which has below class to load some properties -

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "common-list")
@Configuration
@Component
public class CommonConfig{
...
}
```

In my spring boot project, above class/jar is a dependency.
How do i specify where to look for this property "common-list" to load in my project?
OR
Do i need to modify the class/jar, with PropertySource annotation specifying the property file where to look for these common-list values?

I have bootstrap.properties with following line-

```
spring.application.name=xyz
```

xyz.yaml on the config server

```
common-list:
...
```

and by looking at env properties of my spring boot application, i can see the file is picked up and loaded. But CommonConfig instance doesnt get initialized with those files values.
Values are organized correctly as i have tested them by building a spring boot test application in same project where jar is created (all the values populate in CommonConfig instances correctly).

**UPDATED (SOLVED)**
Issue was with converting my object to json string incorrectly, which caused the advice to go in default route instead of picking correct values.

Answer (score 1):

When component scanning picks up this `CommonConfig` class, the `ConfigurationProperties` annotation will basically inject properties found in `application.yml` or `application.properties` that begin with the prefix `common-list.` and set them.

See a DZONE article [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-configurationproperties-1).

Answer (score 0):

i updated the above post with resolution. 
Issue was not with loading configuration properties rather code.